"If this was right, it would mean that equitable rights could not form the subject-matter of a trust"
I'm stymied on  these quotations below by William Swadling†. I know that a sub-trust can hold Equitable Rights. But why would the proposition in italics "mean that equitable rights could not form the subject-matter of a trust" ?

But the more egregious error is to say that the beneficiary has ‘equitable’ title (or sometimes ‘beneficial’ title).  The reason this is wrong is that it creates the impression that the beneficiary has an ‘equitable’ or ‘beneficial’ version of the rights held by the trustee.  In other words, the beneficiary has the same rights as the trustee, albeit that they are recognised by equity and not law, as are the rights of the trustee. [emphasis mine]


If this was right, it would mean that equitable rights could not form the subject-matter of a trust, yet the example of the sub-trust demonstrates that proposition to be false – it is not only legal rights which can be held on trust.


†William Swadling is Professor of Law at the University of Oxford and a Fellow of Brasenose College. He chairs the faculty’s teaching groups in Restitution, Trusts, and Personal Property.  He is particularly interested in the intersection between trusts, property, and restitution, and a number of his articles on this topic have been cited in the English, Australian, and Singaporean courts.


Swadling is too fussy and pedantic for his own good.

@ohwilleke please spell out why?

@useer95921 The way that the terms in question are used by courts and legal practitioners in not nearly as precise and specific as the way he attempts to use the term and his method of analysis is very old school, more typical of the 1920s to 1930s than it is of modern T&E jurisprudence generally.

@ohwilleke are not you assuming that American T&E jurisprudence is the same as British T&E jurisprudence? Perhaps courts and lawyers in England use these terms like Swadling does?
